# How does pyspark read from an an entire directory under the hood?

Tags: pyspark

How does pyspark read from a directory under the hood?

Asking because have situation where I am attempting to read from a dir and then write to that same location later in overwrite mode. Doing this is throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException` errors (even when manually placing files in the dir) and am assuming that this read and overwriting in the cause, so am curious as to the underlying process that spark uses to read from a dir and what could be happening when I try then to overwrite that same dir.

Comment: Hint of an answer can be found here: https://forums.databricks.com/answers/9451/view.html. Will continue looking.

Comment: Not a full answer, so leaving as a comment for now, but a pretty good description of how spark reads files can be found here: https://freecontent.manning.com/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-with-spark/.